# What is concurrent request (-c) in Apache Benchmark?

Tags: apache, apachebench

What is concurrent request (-c) in apache benchmark?

I think it is number of simultaneous request(Process) created in single point of time?

Can anybody explain if I am wrong? Can you give some example how concurrent request will work? How can I test this like `Boundary Value Analysis(BVA)` testing

Comment: It's number of users trying to access the same resource in a given period of time (second).

Comment: So it uses same thread (or different tread?) for all the users ? (Process thread). Will it create any bottleneck if concurrency is more in high traffic site (?)

Comment: Check out [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7688807/3364066). It includes a very lucid description of concurrency.

Answer (score 17):

You are correct.

In simple words, `ab -n 1000 -c 5 http://www.example.com/`

where,

> -n 1000: ab will send 1000 number of requests to example.com server
>   in order to perform for the benchmarking session
>
> -c 5 : 5 is concurrency number i.e. ab will send 5 number of multiple
>   requests to perform at a same time to example.com server

Came across the following SO question where one of the answer says `ab` is not a perfect benchmark tool, since, you have CSS/JS/Images factors to consider when it comes to benchmark - [Can someone please explain what these ApacheBench results mean?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417727/can-someone-please-explain-what-these-apachebench-results-mean)

Comment: I think it's worth saying that, if you try `ab` from the server your app is running on, the results are not going to be accurate, as `ab` will affect your system's performance while running. The best way to test it, is by running `ab` from a remote machine to your app server.

Comment: In your example of -n 1000 and -c 5, does this mean that it will make 5 requests per second, 200 times (so for 200 seconds)? Or can we not control the number of requests it will make per second?

Answer (score 2):

From the [manual page](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/programs/ab.html):
    -c concurrency
    Number of multiple requests to perform at a time. Default is one request at a time.