# Apache Benchmark - concurrency and number of requests

Tags: php, performance, apache, node.js, concurrency

The benchmark documentation says concurrency is how many requests are done simultaneously, while number of requests is total number of requests. What I'm wondering is, if I put a 100 requests at a concurrency level of 20, does that mean 5 tests of 20 requests at the same time, or 100 tests of 20 requests at the same time each? I'm assuming the second option, because of the example numbers quoted below..

I'm wondering because I frequently see results such as this one on some testing blogs:

```
Complete requests: 1000000
Failed requests: 2617614
```

This seems implausible, since the number of failed requests is higher than the number of total requests.

Edit: the site that displays the aforementioned numbers: http://zgadzaj.com/benchmarking-nodejs-basic-performance-tests-against-apache-php

OR could it be that it keeps trying until it reaches one million successes? Hm...

Answer (score 54, accepted):

It means a single test with a total of 100 requests, keeping 20 requests open at all times.  I think the misconception you have is that requests all take the same amount of time, which is virtually never the case.  Instead of issuing requests in batches of 20, ab simply starts with 20 requests and issues a new one each time an existing request finishes.

For example, testing with `ab -n 10 -c 3` would start with3 concurrent requests:

```
[1, 2, 3]
```

Let's say #2 finishes first, ab replaces it with a fourth:

```
[1, 4, 3]
```

... then #1 may finish, replaced by a fifth:

```
[5, 4, 3]
```

... Then #3 finishes:

```
[5, 4, 6]
```

... and so on, until a total of 10 requests have been made.  (As requests 8, 9, and 10 complete the concurrency tapers off to 0 of course.)

Make sense?

As to your question about why you see results with more failures than total requests... <s>I don't know the answer to that.  I can't say I've seen that.  Can you post links or test cases that show this?</s>

Update: In looking at [the source](http://code.google.com/p/apachebench-standalone/source/browse/trunk/ab.c), ab tracks four types of errors which are detailed below the "Failed requests: ..." line:

- Connect - (`err_conn` in source) Incremented when ab fails to set up the HTTP connection
- Receive - (`err_recv` in source) Incremented when ab fails a read of the connection fails
- Length - (`err_length` in source) Incremented when the response length is different from the length of the first good response received.
- Exceptions - (`err_except` in source) Incremented when ab sees an error while polling the connection socket (e.g. the connection is killed by the server?)

The logic around when these occur and how they are counted (and how the total `bad` count is tracked) is, of necessity, a bit complex.  It looks like the current version of ab should only count a failure once per request, but perhaps the author of that article was using a prior version that was somehow counting more than one?  That's my best guess.

If you're able to reproduce the behavior, definitely [file a bug](https://issues.apache.org/bugzilla).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation on concurrency. The link where I saw those results is in the original question, I hope that's example enough. In any case I'll try to replicate the test at work tomorrow and post back if I have anything.

Comment: Hi, when you say `request 2 finsihes`, you mean that Apache Bench get a response for request 2 and after sends `request 1`?

Answer (score 0):

I see nothing wrong. Failed requests can increment more than one error each. That's how `ab` works.

> There are various statically declared buffers of fixed length.
>   Combined with the lazy parsing of the command line arguments,
>   the response headers from the server and other external inputs,
>   this might bite you.

You might notice for example that the previous node results have a similar count for 3 of the error counters. Most probably, from the 100 000 requests made only 8409 failed and not 25227.

```
Receive: 8409, Length: 8409, Exceptions: 8409
```

Comment: The ab source actually documents each counter as "requests failed due to <error type>".  It also looks like they're trying to be good about terminating each request as soon as one of those counters is bumped.  (Or, conversely, only incrementing one err_* counter at the end of a failed request.)  That article is a year old, which is why I'm guessing this may no longer be an issue.  But I don't know for sure.