# Explain About Apachebench output ( ab.exe )

Tags: php, database, apachebench

I have a web production if its many concurrent users, the web will be disconnected from the database , developement using xampp 1.7.3 and PHP language (codeigniter framework)

I want to find the cause by using performance testing ApacheBench, because I was new in this case then I want to get a way to run apache bench correctly,

I also want to get an explanation of the output apache bench I made below..

can anybody help me explain information that output from apachebench ab.exe

my goal to know why the web down after testing with this command :

```
ab -n 1000 -c 50 http://10.10.5.175:8090/ptpn4absensi
```

[image]

and if it can help me to get a solution on this problem, why my web production disconnect from database if they may concurrent user ?

excuse on my bad english..

thx before..

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: is there a more effective way of testing web php ?

Comment: There's plenty of way of testing web php, but not using apache bench against localhost..... what are you actually trying to achieve?

Comment: I have a web production if its many concurrent users, the web will be disconnected from the database
I want to find the cause by using performance testing ApacheBench, because I was new in this case then I want to get a way to run apache bench correctly, I also want to get an explanation of the output apache bench I made above.. thx

Comment: maybe something like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417727/can-someone-please-explain-what-these-apachebench-results-mean?rq=1